# How to filter query value in one if there is few of same value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBYkV.jpg)

This is my html code, I want to filter only to show one time for each user,
I have already changed my views.py to

> allexpelorer   = Destination.objects.filter(destination =
> pk).order_by('-pk')

```
                {% if allexpelorer %}
                {% for allexpelorer in allexpelorer%}
                <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" style="background-color: #ffffff;border: 10px solid  #f7f7f7;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 p-0">
                            {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                            {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allexpelorer.user_pk %}
                            {% if allusersinfo.profilecover %}
                            <img src="{{allusersinfo.profilecover}}" style="height: 80px; width: 100%;">
                            {% else %}
                            <img src="{% static 'front/assets/img/cover.png' %}" style="height: 80px; width: 100%;">
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ml-1" style="margin-top: -26px;">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                                {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allexpelorer.user_pk %}
                                {% if allusersinfo.profileimg %}
                                <img class="img-cls-circle" src="{{allusersinfo.profileimg}}">
                                {% else %}
                                <img class="img-cls-circle" src="{% static 'front/assets/img/blank.png' %}">
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10 mt-4">
                                {% for allusers in allusers %}
                                {% if allusers.pk == allexpelorer.user_pk %}
                                {% if allusers.pk == user.pk %}
                                <h5 class="ml-2"><a href="/profile">{{allusers.first_name}} {{allusers.last_name}}
                                    {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                                    {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allusers.pk%}
                                    {% if allusersinfo.celeberity == 'yes' %}
                                    <i class="fas fa-user-check text-color-tripchiz"></i>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </a></h5>
                                {% else %}
                                <h5 class="ml-2"><a href="{% url 'fprofile' pk=allusers.pk %}">{{allusers.first_name}} {{allusers.last_name}}
                                    {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                                    {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allusers.pk%}
                                    {% if allusersinfo.celeberity == 'yes' %}
                                    <i class="fas fa-user-check text-color-tripchiz"></i>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </a></h5>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ml-1">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                                {% for allusers in allusers %}
                                {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allexpelorer.user_pk and allusers.pk == allexpelorer.user_pk %}
                                <small>Live in <a href="#">{{allusersinfo.live}}</a></small>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                <br>
                                {% for allusersinfo in allusersinfo %}
                                {% for allusers in allusers %}
                                {% if allusersinfo.user_pk == allusers.pk and allexpelorer.user_pk == allusers.pk %}
                                {% for allcommunities in allcommunities %}
                                {% if allcommunities.pk == allusersinfo.orginfrom %}
                                <small>From <a href="{% url 'comprofile' pk=allcommunities.pk %}">{{allcommunities.name}}</a></small>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                <br>
                                {% for allusers in allusers %}
                                {% if allusers.pk == allexpelorer.user_pk %}
                                <small><a href="#">{{allusers.username}}</a></small>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ml-1 mb-2 mt-1">
                            {% if allexpelorer.user_pk != user.pk %}
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="{% url 'chatroom' pk=allexpelorer.user_pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Message</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a href="{% url 'addfriend' pk=allexpelorer.user_pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                <div class="card bg-white card-inout">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-12">
                              <h4 class="text-muted">There is no data to show.</h4>
                              <small class="text-muted">This community doesn't have any explorers.
                              </small>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add more clarity - what you mean by showing one value of the same value? Value of what?

Comment: I want to write a query that get the data from database, there are few values that are the same but I want to get only one of them not all then send it to html

Answer (score 0):

To get the unique values from the query :

```
myfriends = Friends.objects.filter(Q(friend_one = request.user.pk) | Q(friend_two = request.user.pk)).distinct()
```

OR

```
myfriends = set(Friends.objects.filter(Q(friend_one = request.user.pk) | Q(friend_two = request.user.pk)))
```

`myfriends` will have unique values.

Comment: can you update the question with the sample output which you are getting?

Comment: if you need any particular column then use values_list('name', flat=True). and apply distinct() as well. This will give unique values.

Comment: I'll add screen shot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBYkV.jpg     , I want to show only one time

Comment: it would be better if you give output of queryset.

Comment: allexpelorer   = Destination.objects.filter(destination = pk).order_by('-pk')  this is my query

Comment: have you tried with distinct()... Destination.objects.filter(destination = pk).order_by('-pk').distinct()